# Python 2.7, how can I find the position of group of letters in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, position, letters

I need to know how can I find ALL the position of a group of letters in a string. For example, in the string "Canyoucanacanasacannercancanacan" the letters "an" recur 7 times. I want to know the exact position of each one, possibly in a list. How can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: You start by writing code and showing us what you have don't expect us to do for you

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: IMO, "an" is not a **letter** but a substring.

Comment: Please include a previous attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly I couldn't find a duplicate of this question! You can do this using `str.index`, while updating the starting position that you're looking from to exclude parts of the string you've already checked.

```
s = 'Canyoucanacanasacannercancanacan'
position_list = []
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        position = s.index('an', i)
    except ValueError:
        break
    position_list.append(position)
    i = position + 1
print(position_list)
```

As someone suggested, you could also use `str.find`, like this:

```
s = 'Canyoucanacanasacannercancanacan'
position_list = []
i = s.find('an')
while i != -1:
    position_list.append(i)
    i = s.find('an', i+1)
print(position_list)
```

Comment: you could use `.find`, which returns `-1` if not found and then loop over `while found != -1`

Comment: Good suggestion! I don't know which one I prefer.

Comment: well, the one good thing about using `.index` is that it works for *all sequences*, so `tuple`, `list`, `range`, etc

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer), like so:

```
import re

s = "Canyoucanacanasacannercancanacan"
pattern = "an"

result = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(pattern, s)]

assert result == [1, 7, 11, 17, 23, 26, 30]
```

Note that this only finds the *non-overlapping* instances, which in your specific case is all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you can  modify the output as you wish (start and end):

```
import re

text = "Canyoucanacanasacannercancanacan"
for m in re.finditer(r"an", text):
    print('%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0)))
```

The output am getting:

```
01-03: an
07-09: an
11-13: an
17-19: an
23-25: an
26-28: an
30-32: an
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small generator to find all positions of letters in a text:

```
def find_positions(text, letters):
    curr = text.find(letters)
    while curr >= 0:
        yield curr
        curr = text.find(letters, curr + len(letters))
```

Usage:

```
positions = list(find_positions("Canyoucanacanasacannercancanacan", "an"))
print(positions)
```

You get:

```
[1, 7, 11, 17, 23, 26, 30]
```